# Kotlin Crear carpeta en Documents

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Mi pregunta es como crear un directorio público en el dispositivo móvil pero que dependa de la carpeta "Documents" no que esté dentro de mi app, necesito que sea accesible por todos. Les paso el código que puse y el resultado

Gracias !!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto no como imagen por favor, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, mas allá de eso puedes ayudarme?

Answer (score -1):

Asegúrate de tener los permisos declarados en el AndroidManifest.xlm.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si tu utilizas Android 6.0 (Api 23) o superior debes solicitar los permisos explícitamente mediante programación (Asegúrate primero de declarar los permisos en el manifest).

```
// Consultas si el usuario ya concedió el permiso
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Si el usuario no ha concedido el permiso, lo solicitas
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 0);

} else {

    // Si el usuario concedió el permiso, aquí creas la carpeta
}

// Si estas en un fragment utiliza activity en vez de this
// Este código lo puedes colocar el onCreate.
```

Después de que solicites el permiso la aplicación ejecutara el método heredado `onRequestPermissionsResult` para decirte si el usuario acepto el permiso o no (Asegúrate de sobrescribir el método en la actividad o el fragmento).

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // El usuario acepto el permiso. Aquí debes color el código para crear la carpeta

    } else {

        // El usuario no acepto el permiso.
    }
}
```

Este es el código para crear la carpeta. En vez de utilizar `applicationContext` utiliza `Enviroment`. Y asegúrate de obtener los directorios públicos.

```
File parentDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENT)

File newDir = File(parentDir, "newFile");

file.mkdirs()
```

Comment: GRACIAS David lo implementaré y te cuentolos resultados